# Video Player Crashes pathForResource Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, path

Currently i try to setup a small app that simply play a video (just for my daughter) but it always crashes on the "path"

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playVideo()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func playVideo() {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

The crash happens here  `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")`

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   cause path is empty

Comment: Are you  added your file(video.mp4) to "Copy Bundle Resources"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the video in your Xcode target under `Build Phases` to the `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

The NSBundle pathForResource function crashes if it can't locate the file in the bundle. To fix this, you can do something like:

```
let bundlePath:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
let filePath:String = "\(bundlePath)/video.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the video asset file has the 'Target Membership' checkbox checked. Select the asset in the left hand panel 'Project navigator', then in the right hand panel under 'Target Membership' make sure the checkbox is checked next to the project scheme name.